# How to use pipenv in Python shell script?

Tags: python, macos, shell, command-line, pipenv

I needed a module for a shell script I've written in Python, so I used pipenv to install it. I can run the command fine using:

```
~$ pipenv run python3 foo
```

Now, if I want to just run `~$ foo` on the command line (fish shell on MacOS, homebrew installed), how do I invoke the pipenv environment in the shebang of my Python script? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [pipenv-shebang](https://github.com/laktak/pipenv-shebang) you can run your script with

```
pipenv-shebang PATH/SCRIPT
```

or you could insert the shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env pipenv-shebang
```

to run it with just `PATH/SCRIPT`.

Answer (score 5):

As documented here https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ you need to activate the virtual environment first. This will spawn another shell with the virtual environment activated

`$ pipenv shell`

so that you can run

`$ python foo`

to execute your script. Then you can use

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

on the first line of your script and make the script executable (chmod +x foo.py) so that you can run

`$ ./foo`

If the location of that script is part of your `PATH` environment variable, you should be able to run now

`$ foo.py`

If you don't like the extension you will have to remove from your script too

Answer (score 0):

create wrapper file like below works for me, but little bit hacky way.

```
import subprocess
if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.run(['pipenv', 'run', 'foo'])
```