# How can I run a Python pipenv from another directory?

Tags: python, pipenv

I have a project for which I'd now like to use pipenv.

I want to symlink this from my main bin directory, so I can run it from another directory (where it interacts with local files) but nevertheless run it in the pipenv with the appropriately installed files.

Can I do something like

```
pipenv run python /PATH/TO/MY/CODE/foo.py localfile.conf
```

Or is that not going to pick up the pipenv defined in /PATH/TO/MY/CODE/Pipenv ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57332849/52817

Answer (score 34):

Not sure if this was relevant with the version of pipenv you used in 2018, but as of current versions you can use the [PIPENV_PIPFILE](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/advanced/#pipenv.environments.PIPENV_PIPFILE) environment variable.  You will end up with a wrapper shell script that looks something like:

```sh
export PIPENV_PIPFILE=/my/project/dir/Pipfile
exec pipenv run command ...
```

(Answering even though I'm half a year late because this was the first relevant search result, so I can find it again next time.)

Comment: Why is `exec` necessary? I tried it without `exec` and it worked just fine.

Comment: Shouldn't it work as `PIPENV_PIPFILE=/my/project/dir/Pipfile pipenv run command`?

Comment: @JamyMahabier With `exec`, the shell script gets terminated / replaced by the Python process. Without `exec`, the wrapper script will run until the Python script is terminated, which wastes memory, and can cause confusion when sending signals to either process.

Answer (score 5):

pipenv is a wrapper for virtualenv which keeps the virtualenv-files in some folder in your home directory. I found them in `/home/MYUSERNAME/.local/share/virtualenvs`.

So i wrote a `small_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/MYUSERNAME/.local/share/virtualenvs/MYCODE-9as8Da87/bin/activate
python /PATH/TO/MY/CODE/foo.py localfile.conf
deactivate
```

It activates the virtualenv for itself, then runs your python code in your local directory and finally deactivates the virtualenv.

You can replace `localfile.conf` by `$@` which allows you to run `./small_script.sh localfile.conf`.

Comment: One downside of this is that any extra behaviour that `pipenv` has, e.g. [automatically loading `.env` files](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#automatic-loading-of-env), won't be performed. If you just need the right Python interpreter with the right dependencies it works fine.